# Responsive div with CSS

Tags: html, css

I want to make this div responsive but I don't know how to make it. I don't want to use Bootstrap I want a simple code.

I have another question, I want to increase the size of the two image I have tried to increase but with no result.

```
<div class="cc-selector">
    <input id="visa" type="radio" name="credit-card" value="visa" />
    <label class="drinkcard-cc visa" for="visa"></label>
    <input id="mastercard" type="radio" name="credit-card"   value="mastercard" />
    <label class="drinkcard-cc mastercard"for="mastercard"></label>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.cc-selector{
position: relative;
left: 600px;
top: 250;
}
.cc-selector input{
margin:0;padding:0;
-webkit-appearance:none;
   -moz-appearance:none;
        appearance:none;
}
.visa{background-image:url(http://i.imgur.com/lXzJ1eB.png);}
.mastercard{background-image:url(http://i.imgur.com/SJbRQF7.png);}

.cc-selector input:active +.drinkcard-cc{opacity: .9;}
.cc-selector input:checked +.drinkcard-cc{
-webkit-filter: none;
   -moz-filter: none;
        filter: none;
 }
.drinkcard-cc{
cursor:pointer;
background-size:contain;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
display:inline-block;
width:100px;height:70px;
-webkit-transition: all 100ms ease-in;
   -moz-transition: all 100ms ease-in;
        transition: all 100ms ease-in;
-webkit-filter: brightness(1.8) grayscale(1) opacity(.7);
   -moz-filter: brightness(1.8) grayscale(1) opacity(.7);
        filter: brightness(1.8) grayscale(1) opacity(.7);
 }
.drinkcard-cc:hover{
-webkit-filter: brightness(1.2) grayscale(.5) opacity(.9);
   -moz-filter: brightness(1.2) grayscale(.5) opacity(.9);
        filter: brightness(1.2) grayscale(.5) opacity(.9);
 }
```

Comment: What have you tried on your own so far?  Please refer to: [Ask]. Please post a [MCVE]. You also didn't even bother to complete the 2-minute site tour before asking.

Comment: What exactly do you expect the outcome to be? Some screenshots would really help.

Comment: ok i want that when you move the window of the broswer the 2 image move. I want that these div be responsive.

Comment: @pol for example if i move the window of the browser the 2 image moves and when u go at the end of the window width also the image are visible because now the image not move but stay in their position

Comment: @pol for exemple like this : you see that these 2 image are respnsive  link : https://postimg.org/image/5mw2uosy9/

Comment: Please refer to [ask] and take the [tour].

Answer (score 2):

Bootstrap has classes defined to make the layout responsive. If you dont want to use bootstrap then you might as well want to look at **media queries** in CSS. Using media queries you can write your own classes for a responsive design.
For example :

```
@media screen and (min-width: 780px) {
    .class1{
       //define css rules on your div and images when screen size is greater than 780 px
    }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 780px) {
    .class1{
       //define css rules on your div and images when screen size is lesser than 780 px
    }
}
```

After defining the rules you can add these classes to your elements.Similarly you can customise it for more and diff screen sizes if needed.
Let me know in comments if this doesn't help you.